# "\n" in python messes with chmod

Tags: python-3.x, chmod

I am making a program where I need permission to file paths so I am using the chmod command. I get the paths from a text document. I put the paths there and organized them by rows by using the "/n" command. The problem is when I plug the variable in the string still has a /n on it. I was wondering if there was a way to have a txt document go down a line but in a way it wont interfere.

OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: 'C:/Users/*****/Pictures/Camera Roll\n'

I have python 3.6.2 and windows 10. I am still in the early stages of learning this language.

Comment: Does your directory `Camera Roll` have the `\n` at the end of it making it appear as `Camera Roll\n` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to `.strip()` the path before sending it to chmod:

```
st = 'abcd\n'
st.strip() == 'abcd' # strip() trims all whitespace
```